Prove that the function sequence $f_n(x)=n^2\left(\mathrm{e}^{\frac{1}{n x}}-1\right) \sin \frac{1}{n x}$ convergent uniformly on $[a,+\infty)(a>0)$ .
Prove that the function sequence $f_n(x)=n^2\left(\mathrm{e}^{\frac{1}{n x}}-1\right) \sin \frac{1}{n x}(n=1,2, \cdots)$ convergent uniformly on $[a,+\infty)(a>0)$ .
Proof1. For every $x \in[a,+\infty)$, we have
$$
\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} f_n(x)=\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\sin \frac{1}{n x}}{\frac{1}{n x}} \cdot \frac{\mathrm{e}^{\frac{1}{n x}}-1}{\frac{1}{n x}} \cdot \frac{1}{x^2}=\frac{1}{x^2} .
$$
Notice that while $t \rightarrow 0$ , we have
$$
\mathrm{e}^t-1 \sim t+o(t), \quad \sin t \sim t+o(t),
$$
so when $x \in[a,+\infty)$ and $n \rightarrow \infty$ , we have
$$
\begin{aligned}
& \left|n^2\left(\mathrm{e}^{\frac{1}{n x}}-1\right) \sin \frac{1}{n x}-\frac{1}{x^2}\right|=n^2\left|\left(\mathrm{e}^{\frac{1}{n x}}-1\right) \sin \frac{1}{n x}-\frac{1}{n^2 x^2}\right| \\
& \quad=n^2\left|\left[\frac{1}{n x}+o\left(\frac{1}{n x}\right)\right]\left[\frac{1}{n x}+o\left(\frac{1}{n x}\right)\right]-\frac{1}{n^2 x^2}\right| \\
& \quad=n^2 o\left(\frac{1}{n^2 x^2}\right) .
\end{aligned}
$$
So we have
$$
\sup _{x \in[a,+\infty)}\left|n^2\left(\mathrm{e}^{\frac{1}{n x}}-1\right) \sin \frac{1}{n x}-\frac{1}{x^2}\right| \leqslant n^2 o\left(\frac{1}{n^2 a^2}\right) \rightarrow 0 \quad(n \rightarrow \infty) .
$$
This proves $f_n(x) \rightrightarrows \frac{1}{x^2}(x \in[a,+\infty))$.
Proof2:
(a) $f_n(x) \stackrel{x \in(0,+\infty)}{\nrightarrow} f(x)$
$\sup _{x \in(0,+\infty)}\left|f_n(x)-f(x)\right| \geqslant n^2|(e-1) \sin 1-1|\nrightarrow 0$
(b) $f_n(x) \stackrel{x \in[\delta,+\infty)}{\rightrightarrows} f(x)$
Note that $\left|0\left(\frac{1}{n x}\right)\right|=\left|0\left(\frac{1}{n \delta}\right)\right|$
$$
\begin{aligned}
f_n(x)-f(x) & =\frac{1}{x^2}\left[\frac{e^{-n x}-1}{1 / n x} \cdot \frac{\sin \frac{1}{n x}}{1 / n x}-1\right] \\
& =\frac{1}{x^2}\left[\frac{1}{t^2}\left(t+\frac{e^{\theta t}}{2 !} t^2\right)\left(t-\frac{\cos \hat{\theta} t}{3 !} t^3\right)-1\right]\left(t=\frac{1}{n x}\right) \\
& =\frac{1}{x^2}\left[\frac{e^{\theta t}}{2 !} t-\frac{\cos \hat{\theta} t}{3 !} t^2+\frac{e^{\theta t}}{2 !} \frac{\cos \hat{\theta} t}{3 !} t^3\right]
\end{aligned}
$$
When $n$ is large enough, $\exists C \forall x \in[\delta,+\infty)\left|f_n(x)-f(x)\right| \leqslant \frac{1}{\delta^2} \cdot C \cdot \frac{1}{n \delta}\xrightarrow[n \rightarrow+\infty]{} 0$
Which of these two proof ideas is correct?

It’s known that one of them is not correct @xpaul

I didn't see clearly. I thought you wanted to provide two different solutions.

In proof 2(a) we should have $$n^2|(e-1)\sin 1-1|$$

The proof can be presented in a simpler way, and give a stronger conclusion.   Assume $\displaystyle\lim_{t\to 0^+}g(t)= 1$ for a function $g$ defined on $(0,b).$ Let $g_n(t)=g(t/n).$ Obviously $g_n\rightrightarrows 1.$ Define $h_n(x)=g_n(x^{-1}),$ $x>a:=b^{-1}.$ Thus $h_n\rightrightarrows 1$ on $(a,\infty).$ We can apply the above to the function $$g(t)=t^{-2}(e^t-1)\sin t={e^t-1\over t}{\sin t\over t}$$ Observe that $$h_n(x)=n^2x^2(e^{1/nx}-1)\sin(1/nx)$$ As the function $x^{-2}$ is bounded (by $a^{-2})$  we get $$f_n(x)=x^{-2}h_n(x)\rightrightarrows x^{-2}$$ The conclusion $h_n\rightrightarrows 1$ is stronger than $f_n\rightrightarrows x^{-2}$ as the function $x^{-2}$ is not bounded away from $0.$
Concerning the half line $(0,\infty)$ we may restrict to $(0,b].$ Assume that $g(c)\neq 1$ for some $0<c\le b.$ Then
$g_n$ does not converge uniformly to $1$ as $g_n(n^{-1}c)=g(1)\neq 1.$ Thus $h_n$ is not convergent uniformly to $1.$ The latter implies that $f_n$ is not convergent uniformly to $x^{-2},$  as the function $x^{2}$ is bounded for $0<x\le b.$ Again the condition $h_n\not\rightrightarrows 1$ is stronger than $f_n\not\rightrightarrows x^{-2}.$
It remains to show that there is $c$ such that $g(c)\neq 1.$ We have $g(\pi)=0.$   One can verify that actually $g(1)=(e-1)\sin 1\neq 1,$ but that requires some additional effort.
